# How do you authenticate a third party developer to access your API via oAuth 2.0?

Tags: api, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

Suppose I have a working REST API for my product.

I want to give access only to developers who sign up to this product. Also, there will be several plans available so certain parts of the API are not accessible on the free plan.

From the grant types I've seen only the client-credentials one seems to be the closest solution. However that won't authenticate the developer account stored in my product db, it will only get an access token for that client. The user won't actually be 'logged in' per se. Add to that the fact that a single client can be reused by everyone, according to implementations I've seen.

The only way I see is creating a custom grant type, by adding an extra api_key to the client credentials type, which pertains to the developer account.

Is there a way to do this with the existing grant types? Introducing custom types will not work with many oAuth2 libraries out there out of the box and I don't want to give the developers the hassle of modifying them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to invent a custom grant type.

A single client can be reused by everyone ***only if everyone knows the client secret***.

So, it seems that what you have to do is (1) to authenticate a developer when you issue a pair of client ID and client secret to the developer and (2) to motivate the developer not to reveal the client secret to others.

Comment: How do I authenticate the developer before issuing the client_id/secret?